# Phonegap: Parse not initilizing on ios or android

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, parse-platform

I am using Phonegap 3.0, and trying to integrate it with parse so I can sign users in on my app. I have the code written in Javascript and have tested it and it works when run on a browser. I can initilize parse, and create objects on the browser only. When I run the app on an ios or android device the parse code doesn't seem to work/ doesn't get executed.

Things I have tried:
 - Installed the Parse phonegap plugin
 - Added all relevant SDK's suggested by Parse to the source
 - Run the project from XCode and not using "Cordova emulate ios"

I've been looking around for an answer for the last couple days and can't seem to find anything. I'm assuming there is a way to do this, again I want to be able to sign up a user through parse. I am able to do this when the project is run on a browser, but it stops working when run on ios or android emulators and real devices.

```
function tryMe(){

    Parse.initialize("My APP ID", "My Client ID"); //I have my actuals id's here


    alert("Button Clicked");
    var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject");
    var testObject = new TestObject();
    testObject.save({foo: "bar"}).then(function(object) {
        alert("yay! it worked");
    });
    alert("Done")

}
```

This code is run when a button is clicked, its just creating a simple test object. The first alert is executed, but nothing is executed after that, I never see the "yay it worked" or "Done' alerts.

Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT:

Here is the contents of my HTML file, I have encapsulated the parse initilization in the device.ready function, which I can confirm is getting called, and I have included the cordova.js into the file. It's still not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">-->
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


<title>Hello World</title>
```

```
<div id="login_form">

     <input type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
     <input type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
     <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email">
     <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="Password">
     <button id='submit' onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
     <button id='register' onclick="segue('register')">Register</button>
     <button id='login' onclick="segue('login')">Login</button>
     <button id='forgot' onclick="segue('forgot')">Forgot</button>
     <button id='facebook' onClick="facebook()">Facebook</button>
     <button id='twitter' onclick="tryMe()">Twitter</button>
</div>

<script>

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

        Parse.initialize("fVPIrAy0Q5ymJitJPRNALwaVUcNYe9vNL0gGj8hx", "IJ3lsGc6USWSaOlxsc8wJsjNxRA8XuvJ3mI04YuN");

     }, false);

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out the problem. It seems that because I was pulling the Parse sdk from Parse's website

```
<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

It wasn't working on any of the emulators, but it was working on the browser. I manually created a file for the sdk and everything worked.